# how send data from wab page to server using javascript periodically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications

I making a webapp ,in which i want to **send data to server periodically**(with out refreshing) while the user is on some page.how can i do that using JavaScript or ajax or any other technology?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do Ajax requests. Take a look at the following link.

[Jquery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

And use JavaScript's timeInterval() method to send data periodically to server.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to do the work without refreshing page and set Time out function is used to call the function periodically.

```
function test() {
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax/home.html', 
success: function(data)
{
console.log(data);
},
complete: function()
{
setTimeout(test, 5000);
}
});
})};
```